# JSON object undefined

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I've got a an AJAX page request that uses a php file designed to handle queries to my MySQL database. The php file works just fine, but for some reason it's not being nice with me. Here's what I have:

```
    function updateForm(){
        ID = $('#listings').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'query.php',
            data: "query=true" +
                    "&id=" + ID,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                updatePreview();
            }
        });
    }
```

gives me a popup with:

```
{"results":[{"ID":"12","area":"Hoboken","bedrooms":"5","fullbath":"3","halfbath":"1","remarks":"No remarks to speak of.","sqft":"2500","photos":null,"price":"1000","fee":null,"realtor":"Jane Doe","phone":"555-555-5555","address":"10th & Willow","bix":"1"}]}
```

but as soon as I change it to:

```
    function updateForm(){
        ID = $('#listings').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'query.php',
            data: "query=true" +
                    "&id=" + ID,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.results);
                updatePreview();
            }
        });
    }
```

the popup just says undefined.

Ultimately, I want to parse out information and update my page accordingly, but I can't seem to access any of the properties of this JSON object. What's going on?

EDIT:

Here's the code from the php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['query'])){
    if (isset($_POST['id'])){
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM bix WHERE ID=' . get_post('id');
        $listing = mysql_query($query);
        print_json($listing);
    }
}
function print_json($var){
    $output = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($var)) {
        $output["results"][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}

function get_post($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
```

Comment: can you post your server side code?

Comment: also if you console.log() both what do you get?

Comment: maybe you didn't capitalize the T in dataType...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try capitalizing the T in dataType, on the ajax call already?

Answer (score 2):

If it shows you a string in the alert popup it means that the data is a string, not JSON. 
For JSON it shows [Object object].

Check the response type. It should be applicaton/json or applicaton/javascript, not text/plain or something like that.

UPDATE: also make sure the server doesn't return the whole string in quotes. E.g. "[..]" - it just a string then. So use FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools to see what is the actual response. It might help to understand why jQuery doesn't handle it properly.

Comment: This is interesting however according to the jQuery docs a datatype: 'json', is supposed to do the lifting for you... can you post your server side code?

Answer (score 1):

You should `console.log(data)` instead, with this you can see the keys that you can use to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's coming back as parsed json..it's coming back as a string I believe...

use:

```
var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(x.results)
```

Comment: It should, though. The documentation says that datatype: 'json' returns a JSON object, not a string.

Comment: did you try capitalizing the T in dataType, on the ajax call already?

Comment: Ahhh, that's totally what the problem was.

Comment: If you write that in as a response I'll give you the check mark!

Comment: I added a new response. you can check that. glad that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using data instead of data.results or targeting the data.id or data.area and see what it comes up with

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene pointed out, data is a string. Try eval:

```
var stuff = eval(data);
alert(stuff.results);
```

EDIT: this works, but jQuery.parseJSON is probably cooler.